# How do you install Diablo III before purchasing a license?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

Is it possible to download and install Diablo III before purchasing a license; either online from Blizzard, another retailer, or a physical box with a paper slip with magic numbers on it?

Comment: If anyone has an issue with the legality or morality of this question or its answers, please use our [meta] site or our [chat] to voice them.

Comment: Voting to close this as being too localized in time.  This won't be useful at all after the release.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Blizzard has released the Diablo 3 downloaders. They allow you to pre-load the full setup (around 7 GB) on your PC without asking any credentials. Of course without a valid key these files are  completely unusable, they will only work when Blizzard decides to make the game playable on servers through Battle.Net login authentication.

#### Blizzard Downloaders

Here are the downloaders so far available:

**For Windows**

- [DIABLO III Retail (enUS – America)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enUS-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – English)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – Italian)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-itIT-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – French)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-frFR-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – German)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-deDE-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – Polish)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-plPL-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (EU – Spanish)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-esES-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (Latin America – Portuguese)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-ptBR-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (Latin America – Spanish)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-esMX-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (Korean)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-koKR-Installer-downloader.exe)
- [DIABLO III Retail (Taiwan)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-zhTW-Installer-downloader.exe)

**For Mac**

- [DIABLO III Retail Mac version (enUS – America)](http://us.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enUS-Installer-downloader.app.zip)
- [DIABLO III Retail Mac version (EU – English)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer-downloader.zip)
- [DIABLO III Retail Mac version (EU – German)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-deDE-Installer-downloader.zip)
- [DIABLO III Retail Mac version (EU – French)](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-frFR-Installer-downloader.app.zip)

Links above have been listed by [Diablo Inc Gamers](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/download-diablo-iii-now/). Moderators on Blizzard official forum have not had any problems with them and they are already helping people have trouble with downloader so I consider "*them safe to use*".

Comment: Deleting your comment taht says otherwise? Really? You can also find MAC lins here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/qxyxm/diablo_3_windows_and_mac_download_links_all/

Comment: My comment was wrong and I deleted, the only matter for me is provide accurate answers that could help others. I updated the list with additional Mac downloader links found at the Reddit page.

Comment: I think that bad answers help too, becasue other can learn from your mistakes. (but thats for meta discussion)

Comment: You can always log-in in a friend/family account that has D3 already. Then download it from there. I did it with my wife, before she brought her D3.

Comment: @BryanDrewery, EdgeSuite.net is run by [Akamai](http://wiredpen.com/2010/09/01/what-is-edgesuite-net/), who are a large content delivery network.  Blizzard, and many other companies, use them to host large files or other cached items.  While it's still possible that these could be malicious, the chances are relatively slim.  Additionally, the digital signature on at least the US one indicates it was signed by Blizzard, which is another vote of confidence for it being legitimate.

Comment: @Drake Can you re-write your answer to exclude details about the game launch, seeing as how it's passed?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Ok, I put it on my todo list. :)

Answer (score 3):

I just got hold of official Diablo III installer downloader (EU client)

Friend sent me a link which he used to download the downloader and it works for me also.
I have used the link -> downlaoded the downlaoder -> now I'm downloading the client.

I have seen no EULA, agreed to nothing. So as far as law in my counry goes - I'm 100% legal.

BTW the dowloader is disguised torrent client

Thanks to **[bummzack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64990/can-i-pre-load-diablo-iii-client-without-purchasing-it-directly-from-battle-net#comment91488_65019)** here is link to all clients
http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/qxyxm/diablo_3_windows_and_mac_download_links_all/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is accurate. Blizzard has no intention to prevent downloading of the installer files. They sell the key and access to battle.net, not the files. Without paying the installation files are worthless anyway and the more people downloading it, the better.

Comment: To back up my point: All installer file links have been posted to [reddit.com/r/Diablo](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/qxyxm/diablo_3_windows_and_mac_download_links_all/).

Comment: About seeing no EULA: if it's going to work like WoW, you'll get your ToS and various agreements AFTER you're logged in (in World of Warcraft you have to agree again with the Terms everytime a new patch is deployed)

Comment: @Kappei yes I know, but a lot of people accused me of piracy just because I wanted to download original client.