# How do I re-download the Diablo III installer on another computer?

Tags: diablo-iii

I bought Diablo III from Blizzard. Why won't it let me re-download it on another computer?

Comment: How does it not allow you? Error messages? If you want others to help you, at least be a little more elaborate with the description of the issue. People don't read minds unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the game and install it on as many computers as you wish. In fact, since your game purchase is tied to your Battle.net account, [you can download the game even if you haven't bought it yet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70374/do-i-need-to-own-diablo-iii-to-download-and-install-the-game).

[This post has a list of links to various versions of the game's installer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64995/274). You can also re-download the game by logging in to your Battle.net account and clicking the "[Download Game Clients](https://us.battle.net/account/management/download/)" link.